# How to delete the jquery collapsable data-role="collapsible"

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/24/

On click of a delete button , i am trying to delete the  current jquery collapsable div .

The event is being captured , but the current jquery collapsable is not getting delete

This is my code , could you please let me know how to delte the current jquery collapsable ??

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.labelDelIcon')) {
            $(this).closest('#data').remove();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }, true // Capture event
);
```

Could you please let me know how to delete the current jquery data-role="collapsible"

Comment: Id should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `class` Instead of `Id` and then try this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).is('.labelDelIcon')) {
            $(event.target).closest('.data').remove()
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }, true // Capture event
);
```

> Note: *$(this)* is current object here refers to the **Document** I have
>   used *$(event.target)* for currect object.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/26/)

Comment: Glad it helped you @Kiran. Enjoy scripting

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, **the ID attribute must be unique**. JavaScript will only look for the very first matching ID, then stop searching.

In your HTML, change all instances of `id="data"` to `class="data"`, then modify your JavaScript to:

```
$(this).closest('.data').remove();
```

Comment: Thank you but this was not generated by me , but by the jquery framework itself .

Comment: @Kiran I have no idea what you mean. jQuery doesn't generate ID attributes by itself, and it certainly wouldn't generate the same ID unless you specifically told it to use an ID of "data" for both instances.

Comment: But even though i chnaged the id to class and tried its not removing , please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/25/  could you please let me know why ??

Comment: @Kiran you have a lot of problems in your code. I suggest going through http://learn.jquery.com and possibly also trying out a HTML tutorial on Codecademy.

Comment: @Kiran 1. You're mixing native JavaScript with jQuery - either use one or the other, not both. `$('.labelDelIcon').click(...)`. 2. Nested `a` elements are invalid as far as I'm aware, and certainly aren't necessary for the structure you're after.